# Extraño resultado en la consulta del número de filas de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Al realizar una consulta en el modelo y luego llamar a la función desde el controlador, ésta imprime un resultado poco acorde a lo que debería, pero no veo dónde está el error. Por ejemplo, si añado una columna, la cuenta, pero si sigo añadiendo no.

La consulta en sí es para realizar un recuento del número de filas de la tabla entregas.

**Base de datos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Controlador**

```
 public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        //$this->load->model('Entregas_Model');
        //$this->load->model('Entregas_Model');
        $this->Entregas_Model->get_rows($idCarga);

        //$crud->unset_bootstrap();
        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/header.php'  ------------- /
        $datos = array(
            'title' => "Solicitudes", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
            'username' => "Administrador"
        );

        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

        //Quitamos los botones de añadir y quitar
        //$crud->unset_add();
        //$crud->unset_edit();
        //Limitando el número de filas
        /* if ($crud->limit(3, 0)) {

          echo 'Reached limit';
          } */

        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');

        $crud->set_table('entregas');
        $crud->unset_columns(array('accion', 'estado'));

        $crud->display_as('idIntervaloHorario', 'Franja Horaria');
        $crud->display_as('idAcciones', 'Acción');
        $crud->display_as('idEstadoSolicitud', 'Estado Solicitud')->display_as('fechaCita', 'Fecha Cita')
                ->display_as('horaCita', 'Hora Cita')
                ->display_as('numeroEntrega', 'Nº Entrega')
                ->display_as('Origen', 'Orígen')
                ->display_as('cargaPrevista', 'Carga Prevista')
                ->display_as('entregaPrevista', 'Entrega Prevista');


        //Clausula where
        $crud->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario =', $idCarga);

        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');

        $crud->set_relation('idCarga', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');

        $crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');
        //Relación con la tabla acciones
        $crud->set_relation('idAcciones', 'acciones', 'nombreAccion');
        //Relación con la tabla estado
        $crud->set_relation('idEstadoSolicitud', 'estadosolicitudes', 'nombreEstado');

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);

        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }
```

**Modelo**

```
public function get_rows($idCarga) {
        //$this->db->select('COUNT(idCarga)');
        $this->db->from('entregas');
        $this->db->join('intervalosHorarios', 'entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idIntervaloHorario');
        //$this->db->on('entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idCarga');
        $this->db->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario', $idCarga);

        $q = $this->db->count_all_results();

        //$q = $this->db->get()->row();
        //$q = $this->db->result_array();
        print_r($q);

        //$this->db->last_query();

        return $q;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución correcta es:

**En el modelo**

```
public function get_rows($idCarga) {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM entregas LEFT JOIN intervaloshorarios on entregas.idCarga = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario
        WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = ' . $idCarga . ';');

        echo $query->num_rows();


        return $query;
    }
```

**En el controlador(versión reducida)**

```
 public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
      //Añadir esta línea para llamar a la función del modelo
        $this->Entregas_Model->get_rows($idCarga);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira, ésto no me cuadra:

```
//$this->db->select('COUNT(idCarga)');
        $this->db->from('entregas');
        $this->db->join('intervalosHorarios', 'entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idIntervaloHorario');
        //$this->db->on('entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idCarga');
        $this->db->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario', $idCarga);
```

En parte por las lineas comentadas, y , por el formato de tu Join.
Creo que redunda lo siguiente en la clausula Join

```
entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idIntervaloHorario
```

Algo mas parecido a ésto creo que funcionará (llevado a la sintaxis de, creo que es CodeIgniter):

```
Select Count(idCarga)
From entregas join intervalosHorarios
On entregas.idCarga = intervaloHorarios.idCarga
```

Comment: Hola! he probado tu forma y no parece funcionar, me obliga a esta línea: `entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idIntervaloHorario`, tampoco me funciona lo siguiente: `$query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(idCarga) FROM entregas en
        JOIN intervaloshorarios in on en.idCarga = in.idIntervaloHorario
        WHERE en.idIntervaloHorario = ' . $idCarga . ';');`

Comment: Al final he quitado los alias de la consulta y me devuelve lo siguiente: `SELECT COUNT(idCarga) FROM entregas JOIN intervaloshorarios on entregas.idCarga = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = 1;` por lo que entiendo que la consulta la hace, el problema es que no me devuelve el número de filas exacto

Comment: Solucionado, dejo la respuesta más abajo